# Issue while copying plugin to jenkins/plugins directory.

Tags: plugins, jenkins, perforce

I am working on Ubuntu. And need to copy perforce plugin file to jenkins/plugins directory. Since the directory is owned by jenkins user; I want to logon as jenkins user to do any work in this directory. How can I get jenkins user's passowrd? Am I going in the right direction? In general what is the preferred method of copying files to a directory in Ubuntu not owned by current user.

The perforce plugin does not appear on the plugin manager page; hence going the download+copy route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To logon as jeknins user, I couldn't simply use `su jenkins` as I didn't have jenkins user's password. So I used:

```
$ sudo su jenkins
```

Also, after I looked again at the 'Manage plugins' page, I found perforce plugin. Somehow, I missed it on my first pass.