# All Jenkins plugins are lost when migrating to new Jenkins Server

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins server version 1.584 which has at least 50 plugins.

I wanted to check whether i can do an update for the jenkins core, and I didn't want to do it on the original server. Therefore I copied all the folders (expect the builds and modules folders that were under jobs folder) and then started jenkins.
Now it looks like i have no plugin installed at all.

Hope to hear about some way to handle it...

Thanks.
 [image: here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Did you copy the plugins folder to the new Jenkins home ?
It should work.

[image]

Comment: Sure i did, and still the problem is not solved. also tried to reload, tried to change permissions / owner of the folders and files...

Comment: According to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531689/issue-while-copying-plugin-to-jenkins-plugins-directory you need to look more closely on your permissions. Maybe 'run as administrator' ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also copy those *.xml configuration files from `your_old_server_jenkins_home/*` into `your_new_server_jenkins_home/*` ?